# Unexpected result for number_format and sprintf when trying to display number with two decimals

Tags: php, printf, number-formatting

I have a calculation that returns this `double`: 6.4971508379888. If I cast it to a `float` and echo it, it's the same number. I want to display (not round) the number with only two decimals, so I tried:

```
number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '')
```

and

```
sprintf('%0.2f', (float)$number)
```

but in both cases I see 6.50 instead of 6.49. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP automatically round the value based on given precision

If you want your expected results then follow the following code.

```
$precision = 2;
$number = floor($number * pow(10,$precision))/pow(10,$precision);
echo number_format((float)$number, $precision, '.', '');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed how I solved it. I was wondering why number_format and sprintf work this way. I just found out number_format apparently rounds, but it isn't well documented. Not sure about sprintf though?

Comment: This answer was giving me incorrect results for some numbers like **2401.93**. It was causing the number to be rounded down to **2401.92**. I made a modification to the solution above:

`$number = floor($number * pow(10, ($precision + 1))) / pow(10, ($precision + 1));`

This consistently gave me more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight modification to the accepted answer because the solution provided wasn't giving an accurate result. It was causing the last digit to get rounded (down).

```
$digits = 2;
$number = floor($number * pow(10, ($digits + 1)) / pow(10, ($digits + 1));
echo number_format($number, $digits, '.', '');
```

Also, there should be no need to type-cast to a float when passing the number to `number_format()`. The calculation (and the function itself) will automatically set the type accordingly.